# групповое переименование *.tga файлов (3620 штук)

Tags: изображения

Здравствуйте. Есть куча tga файлов (3620), которые нужно переименовать в вид:

test001
...
...
test3620

Как это можно совершить? Можно ли сделать это через cmd/powershell или есть программы, которые позволяют сделать это?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для работы с файлами используй файловый менеджер [тотал командер](https://www.ghisler.com/download.htm). Там есть стандартная функция групповое переименование:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заходишь в папку **--->** нажимаешь ctrl+a (выделение всех файлов) **--->** нажимаешь ctrl+m (групповое переименование) **--->** задаёшь шаблон как на скрине (test[C]) **--->** нажимаешь выполнить.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ!